# Can't read UTF-8 BOM \xef\xbb\xbf

Tags: python, character-encoding

I can't get around this error trying to read a file starting with \xef\xbb\xbf

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 63675320: invalid continuation byte

```
openit = [any1file for any1file in os.listdir('.') if any1file.endswith('.Log')]
if len(openit) != 1:
raise ValueError('should be only one Log file in the current directory')
openit0 = openit[0]
```

What I have tried (separately) so far ;

```
openitx = open(openit0, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
openitx = open(openit0, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
openitx = open(openit0, mode='r', encoding='None')
openitx = open(openit0, mode='r', encoding=None)
openitx = open(openit0, mode='r', encoding='utf-16-le')
openitx = open(openit0, mode='r')

test = openitx.read()

openitx = Path('ncclog.Log', encoding='UTF-8').read_text()
openitx = Path('ncclog.Log', encoding='UTF-8-Sig').read_text()

with open(openit0, mode='r') as file: #Tried with utf-8, utf-8-sig, nothing
 rfile = file.read()
```

When I open with 'rb' I am able to read the file, but I don't want to open it that way.

```
openitx = open(openit0, mode='rb')
openit1 = openitx.read()
```

output looks like

b'\xef\xbb\xbf*** followed by the rest of the file.

I also tried to open it with rb, re.sub the xef\xbb\xbf but havn't been successful with that yet.
The file is 65 mb and when reading 'rb' and printing to a new file, that file is all one line and very slow to open/work with.

Every answer I found online had said to use utf-8-sig, utf-8, or none. I am using python 3.9.6 and couldn't get any of those suggestions to work.

Comment: Given that the error talks about invalid utf8 codes in position 63675320 what makes you think this has anything to do with the byte order mark?

Comment: A bad byte 63MB into the file makes me think it was just written incorrectly.  You need to fix the file, not the code.

Comment: The thought never occurred to me that the file itself was made incorrectly, thank you both for your input. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The file **is not valid UTF-8.** It may contain errors. It may be a different encoding.

The error could be caused by an incomplete write, followed by a write containing a BOM.

### Option 1: Replace the errors

Invalid UTF-8 characters will be replaced with `\uFFFD`.

```py
openitx = open(openit0, mode='r', errors='replace')
```

### Option 2: Parse as binary

You can open the file in binary mode, which gives you raw bytes instead of strings.

```py
openitx = open(openit0, mode='rb')
```

If you are reading the file line by line, or scanning it with regular expressions, some of these things will still work... you will need to use binary regular expressions, though (add the `b` prefix to the string you use for a regular expression, like use `b'^#.*'` instead of `'^#.*'`).

You will probably have to decode the bytes after parsing anyway, but parsing as bytes may make it easier for you to figure out how to handle errors, and it will preserve the invalid data for later in the process.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I tried errors= replace and got UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: utf-8-sig errors=replace gives me this error; can't encode character '\u0650'

Comment: I had not tried rb with the regex I was trying to do, I'll try that next. Thank you!

Comment: @Cogu: If you're getting "can't encode character" then your problem is in a **different part of the code.** When you open a file for reading, it **decodes** characters but does not **encode** them.